# Selenium Click on a button in a new opened window

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

In my page, I have a button that open a new window, I can type some text in a textbox, but I can't click on a link (There isn't any error, but nothing happens).

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//img[@alt='Rechercher']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//img[@alt='Rechercher']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>name=newWin</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>nom</td>
    <td>atexo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Rechercher</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ClickAt command as below:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>link=Rechercher</td>
    <td>1,1</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thnx Surya for your answer. I converted my tests to JUnit 4 tests and it works normaly. But the use of clickAt didn't change any thing. The popup still present and nothing happened.